# Grouping by a column using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got the following model in RoR:

```
rails g model MyTable col1:string col2:integer
```

I then added the following data to it:

```
col1|col2 
a__ |7__ 
a__ |3__ 
b__ |5__ 
b__ |2__
```

I want to group by col1 and get the sum of col2 for each group. I did the following:

```
data = MyTable.all
data2 = data.select("col1, SUM(col2) as col2_all").group("col1")
```

The second line gives the following SQL:

```
SELECT col1, SUM(col2) as col2_all FROM "my_tables" GROUP BY "my_tables"."col1"
```

But the output I get doesn't look right:

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<MyTable id: nil, col1: "a">, #<MyTable id: nil, col1: "b">]>
```

I don't seem to get col2_all as I expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyTable.group(:col1).sum(:col2)`

Comment: Is there ever a time where you would do something like: data2 = data.select("col1, SUM(col2) as col2_all").group("col1")  ?
What is this actually doing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that, if col2_all isn't an attribute of your MyTable model, you're not going to see it.

Does this work?

```
MyModel.group(:col1).sum(:col2)
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. And like you said, if col2_all isn't an attribute in the model, then I don't see it. But if I go: data2 = data.select("col1, SUM(col2) as col2").group("col1"), it seems to work... any ideas?